# Java - split string into seperate words and add something to them

Tags: java

lets say Ive got string:

```
Java Android iOS
```

I need the output of it like this:

```
%java%
%android%
%ios%
```

or

```
%java%%android%%ios%
```

How can I do that?

Sorry, perhaps I didnt explain it okay.

```
String tok[]=input1.split(" ");
        for(String t:tok){
            System.out.println("%"+t.toLowerCase()+"%");
        }
```

that could be good answer but I forgot to mention that I need this saved, not only printed so best result would be as in example 2, so just adding %..% around every word

Comment: By writing some code.

Comment: Show us how you are doing this and why it's not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: `Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")).map(String::toLowerCase).map(s -> "%" + s + "%").collect(Collectors.joining("\n");`

Answer (score 5):

Try following:

```
String test="Java Android iOS";
        String tok[]=test.split("\\s+");
        for(String t:tok){
            System.out.println("%"+t.toLowerCase()+"%");
        }
```

**Output :**

```
%java%
%android%
%ios%
```

Basically all you need is to split the string from space character which can be done by [split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) and than append stuff as you like.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `replaceAll()` and `split()` like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Java Android iOS";
    s = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\b", "%$1%"); // capture and add
    String[] arr = s.split("\\s+");
    for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
%Java%
%Android%
%iOS%
```

Comment: okay, that line  input1 = input1.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\b", "%$1%");  was what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public String wrap(String input)
{
    String[] words = input.split(" "); //get array of words
    StringBuilder sb = new StreingBuilder(); //this is for perfomance
    for(String word : words) //affect each word in string
    {
        sb.append("%").append(word).append("%");
        //add %current_word% to result (if need, you may add space too
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
String x = "I love java programming";
        String arrayX[] = x.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i<arrayX.length; i++){
            System.out.println("%"+arrayX[i].toLowerCase()+"%");
        }
```

output:
%I%
%love%
%java%
%programming%

Comment: The modulus is separated in newline if you run the code

Answer (score 0):

```
String example = "Java Android Ios";
String token[] = example.split("\\s+");

for(int i = 0; i < token.length; i++)  
{
     //%java%%android%%ios%
    System.out.print("%" + token[i].toLowerCase() + "%");
 //%java%
 //%android%
 //%ios%}
System.out.println("%" + token[i].toLowerCase() + "%");
```